# Debian: automatic notification of updates?

Tags: security, debian

What's the simplest way of getting notified of security updates for packages I have installed on my Debian system?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like setting up apticron.  It willnotify by email and download, not install, the packages.

- http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/491
- http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=apticron

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways and packages to do this, but I think the *simplest* way is this cron job:

```
0 */8 * * *     apt-get -qq update && apt-get -dqq dist-upgrade && apt-get -qq --simulate dist-upgrade | grep ^Inst
```

This sends a mail to root whenever there is a package to be upgraded, which in a stable release means mostly security updates.  As a general matter, you should of course redirect the root mail to somewhere you can read it.

I have been using this for some years in a personal environment, and it works great.

Comment: Every 8 hours?  Isn't that a big excessive?

Comment: Zoredache: Excessive how?  Security updates can happen any time, and even the regular mirror pushes are 4 times a day.  So 8 hours are indeed excessively seldom. ;-)  In fact, on newer installations I run similar probes hourly.

Comment: Excessive in that re-downloading the package databases that frequently would take a significant amount of bandwidth on repo servers, if you where pointing at the official repositories.  If you are not using a local apt proxy, then doing that on lots of machines seems somewhat abusive to me.  I find it somewhat difficult to believe that you are actually installing updates every 1 or 8 hours.  If you want immediate notification of an update wouldn't it be better to subscribe to the security RSS & maillist?

Comment: apt-get does not re-download the entire package database.  See pdiff files.  If nothing changes, you end up downloading a few bytes.  And yes, I do use local mirrors/proxies when appropriate.  And yes, I do pull updates several times a day.  The background of that is more complex, however, and might be the subject of another question.